# BackgroundView for section in the tableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I use this function to add background view in my `TableView` when it's empty.

```
func emptyTableViewMessage(with message: String) {
    let messageLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: todoTableView.bounds.size.width/2, y: todoTableView.bounds.size.height / 2 , width: todoTableView.bounds.size.width, height: todoTableView.bounds.size.height))
    messageLabel.text             = message
    messageLabel.textColor        = UIColor.gray
    messageLabel.font             = UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 15)
    messageLabel.textAlignment    = .center
    todoTableView.backgroundView = messageLabel
}
```

I call it in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearching {
        if searchedData?.count == 0 {
            emptyTableViewMessage(with: "Not found")
        } else {
            emptyTableViewMessage.backgroundView = .none
        }

        return (searchedData?.count)!
    }
```

But if I have few section, For example one of them is empty, how Can I add this kind of backgroundView inside the section (not in the header, because I have different items in the header)

Many thanks

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called many, many times. That is not the place to be calling your `emptyTableViewMessage` method. Call it when you actually load your data, not from any of the data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could created an empty cell prototype, this one will be use when there is no data to show. Then let's modify your `emptyTableViewMessage` method to return a `UILabel`.

```
func emptyTableViewMessage(with message: String) -> UIView {
  let messageLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: table.bounds.size.width/2, y: table.bounds.size.height / 2 , width: table.bounds.size.width, height: table.bounds.size.height))
  messageLabel.text = message
  messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
  messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 15)
  messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
  return messageLabel
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` when there is no data to show lets return 1 (to display the Not Found text). If there is data to show let's return how many rows.

```
guard let dataFound = searchedData?.count else { return 1 }
return dataFound > 0 ? dataFound : 1
```

Finally in `cellForRowAt` you dequeue the appropriate prototype cell based on `searchData?.count`.

```
let notFound = searchData?.count > 0 ?? false
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: notFound ? "NotFoundCellId" : "CellId") else { return UITableViewCell() }
if notFound {
  cell.backgroundView = emptyTableViewMessage(with: "Not Found")
} else {
  cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row]
}
```

I quickly created a small project to test this and seems to work fine, you can check it at [Github](https://github.com/acyrman/StackOverflow57746413). The project doesn't manage the data how it should be done for a production code, the search bar doesn't displays well on simulator for iPhone X and newer, etc.; it's just a quick sample on how to display the Not Found text in a table view with many sections so you can have an idea how to do it.
Some screenshots:

**No filter**

[image: Not filtered]

**Filtered by "ica"**

[image: Filtered by: "ica"]

**Filtered by "an"**

[image: Filtered by: "an"]

Hope this helps you!